# Angular directive set scope watch to disabled button

Tags: angularjs

I want to make disabled  a button based on scope changes.

Here is my current directive code:

```
function disabledButton(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        priority:1001,
        scope:{
            isLoading: '=loading'
        },
        link:(scope, element, attrs, isLoading)=>{
            scope.$watch('isLoading', () => {
                element.attr('disabled', true);
            });
       }
    }
}
```

my html:

```
<button type="submit" class="pull-right" disabled-button>Update</button>
```

My Controller just a simple:

```
 $scope.loading = true;
```

But it's not working. The button is not disabled.

Any solution?

JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ssuhat/gp6tq0Lt/7/

Comment: Please provide JSFiddle with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link` and `compile` do not work together.

In the directive definition object, if you only define link, that's like shorthand for having an empty compile function with an empty `preLink` function with your code in the `postLink` function. As soon as you define `compile`, `link` is ignored by angular, because `compile` should return the linking functions.

If you only return one function from `compile`, then it'll be executed post link.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.loading = !$scope.loading;
    }
  })
  .directive('disabledButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        isLoading: '='
      },
      compile: function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log(element);
          var loading = scope.isLoading;
          scope.$watch('isLoading', function(a, b) {
            element.attr('disabled', a);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <button ng-click="change()">dsa</button>
    <div class="row">
      <button is-loading="loading" disabled-button>Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I try to update it become like this https://jsfiddle.net/ssuhat/gp6tq0Lt/13/ why the button can't be toggle?. But the console.log keep getting update

Comment: The problem was that you didn't add attribute "disabled" in your button HTML

Comment: If you don't mind can you kindly explain why it need to jsonparse?

Comment: This is because I treat isLoading as a string ( isLoading: "@"). So string is always true as long is not empty.  The easiest methot to parse string is JSON.parse("true") === true and JSON.parse("false") === false; @SSuhat

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gp6tq0Lt/18/ - this is a version without JSON.parse; I had to change observe to watch and "@" to "=". @SSuhat

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive provided by AngularJS.

```
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="isLoading">Button</button>
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry but this will be my last option. I try to keep my html clean using directive. so I can call it dynamically. Thanks

Comment: ng-disabled is a directive, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: Yes. I tried to not to keep put ng-disabled every button i have. Thanks.

Comment: @Tome Pejoski, instead of adding a new answer, you should amend your existing answer.

Comment: @SajanChandran it was different approach that contained code. Also my first question was correct but the user who asked don't want to use it :)

Comment: @Tome Pejoski yes but still you should add your new answer to your existing answer.

Comment: @SajanChandran ok, thanks for the suggestion. I'll now for now on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.prop('disabled', true);` instead of `element.attr('disabled', true);`

Also please make sure to add else statement in the `$watch` statement to re enable  the button.